# Makefile function expansion

Tags: makefile

```
build_debug:=dltvr
define debug
$$(findstring $(2),$$(if $$(DEBUG_SCOPE_DIR),$$(if $$(filter $$(DEBUG_SCOPE_DIR)%,$(1)),$(build_debug)),$(build_debug)))
endef   
define warn
$$(if $(call debug,$(1),$(2)),$$(warning $(3)))
endef   
$(call warn,jianxi,d,D jianxi)
```

In my optinion, `$(call warn,...)` will be expand to

```
$(if $(findstring d,$(if $(DEBUG_SCOPE_DIR),$(if $(filter $(DEBUG_SCOPE_DIR)%,jianxi),dltvr),dltvr)),$(warning D jianxi))
```

And will output `Makefile:13: D jianxi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; `$(call warn,...)` will be expanded to `$(if $(findstring ...)...)`. But it will **not** be expanded any further.

You have escaped the '$' symbols too far. Try this:

```
define warn
$(if $(call debug,$(1),$(2)),$(warning $(3)))
endef
```